# Restrict access to specific content

Tags: permissions, content-restriction

I need to create several users in WP and to restrict their permissions to specific contents.
For example: I create a custom content type called "Cook Profile" with several text fields and the possibility to insert attachments. User Foo must access only his own Cook Profile.
In add he must be able create posts, but he can only delete or modify his own posts.

Is that possibile? Is there a plugin that make this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) plugin.

Comment: As far as I can see, it's not the right solution. I need something that allows me to be more specific. Thanks, of course!